# Symfony Doctrine Many to Zero Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm fairly new to Symfony and Doctrine and I'm not sure if this can even be done.  I can do it in flat php but can't seem to find a way of doing it in Symfony/Doctrine.  I've gone through loads of Stack Overflow questions and scoured Google but no joy.

I'm working on a project that saves basic information about people such as their name and title etc.  It also saves information about their employer/organisation.  It has two entities/tables.  The first is called CrmPerson (to store information about the person).  This table has a primary key called personid and a foreign key called orgid.  The second table CrmOrg to store data about their organisation.  This table has a primary key called orgid and no foreign key.

Many people can work for one organisation and one organisation can have many people.  I.e. many to one. I've been able to build a single form so that when you enter information about the person and their organisation, when you hit submit it will submit the person information to the CrmPerson table and their organisation information to the CrmOrg table.

However, I have a problem.  In some cases a person may not belong to an organisation at all. A many to zero (I think... if there is such a thing!). When person information is entered into the form but no organisation information is entered, it submits the person's information as a new record to the CrmPerson table (as expected) but it also submits an empty record in the CrmOrg table with no data in any of the fields apart from the primary key orgid (as expected but not wanted). The foreign key orgid is also populated in the CrmPerson table that links to the new empty row in CrmOrg.  This could potentially lead to hundreds/thousands of empty records in CrmOrg.

Is it possible to make it happen so that if person information is added to the form but no company information, only a record is submitted to the CrmPerson table including an empty/null value for the foreign key orgid as well as adding nothing to the CrmOrg table at all?

Here is the code I'm trying to do this with (with parts removed that aren't relevant to the question):

**CrmOrg.php**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/CrmOrg.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
  * CrmOrg
  *
 * @ORM\Table(name="crm_org", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="index_org", columns=
 {"orgid", "memberid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CrmOrg
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orgid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $orgid;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CrmPerson", 
mappedBy="crmorg")
     */
    protected $crmpersons;

    /**
     * CrmOrg constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->crmpersons = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

**CrmPerson.php**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="personid", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $personid;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\CrmOrg
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CrmOrg")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orgid", referencedColumnName="orgid")
 * })
 */
private $orgid;



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CrmOrg", inversedBy="crmpersons", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orgid", referencedColumnName="orgid", nullable=false)
 */
protected $crmorg;
```

**PersonController.php**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/PersonController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\CrmPersonType;
use AppBundle\Entity\CrmPerson;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;




class PersonController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

/**
 * @Route("/user/person_add", name="person_add")
 */
public function personAddAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CrmPersonType::class);



    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $crmperson = $form->getData();

        $em->persist($crmperson);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('lead');
    }

    return $this->render(':lead:lead.add.html.twig', [
        'leadForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

**CrmPersonType**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/CrmPersonType.php


namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Entity\CrmPerson;
use AppBundle\Entity\CrmOrg;
use AppBundle\Form\CrmOrgType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;


class CrmPersonType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, array(
                  'choices'  => array(
                        'Mr' => 'Mr',
                        'Miss' => 'Miss',
                        'Mrs' => 'Mrs',
                        'Ms' => 'Ms',

                                    ),
                  'required'   => false,
            ))

            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  )) 
            ->add('middleNames', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  )) 
            ->add('surname', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))
            ->add('tel', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))
            ->add('mob', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))
            ->add('email', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))
            ->add('jobTitle', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))

            ->add('crmorg', CrmOrgType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Save',
                'attr'  => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
```

**CrmOrgType**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/CrmPersonType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class CrmOrgType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('companyName', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))
            ->add('companyWebsite', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  ))
            ->add('industry', TextType::class, array(
                  'required'   => false,
                  )) 


        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `@JoinColumn` annotation for `$orgid`, add `nullable=true` parameter:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="orgid", referencedColumnName="orgid", nullable=true)
```

That way, you don't have to associate a User with any Organization.

By the way, if you have only one join column, there's no need to put `@JoinColumn` annotation inside `@JoinColumns`. You can simply put the `@JoinColumn` annotation right below `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly!  I've added the nullable=true but it still adds a new record to the CrmOrg table. Is there anything else I might be missing?  By the way thanks for the tip about the @JoinColumns I've removed that too!

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. Try adding `['required' => false]` to `crmorg` field in `CrmPersonType`.

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid.  I've added required false and cleared the cache from the command line and it still doesn't work.  I don't seem to be having much luck with Symfony!